# Gradle не видит библиотеку

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Опубликовал библиотеку на bintray.com и jCenter, пользуясь этой инструкцией:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/266801

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все успешно загрузилось и опубликовалось, однако при подключении библиотеки Gradle выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: Покажите build.gradle, который для приложения именно.

Comment: попробуйте использовать не 1.0.1, а 1.0.2 - если внимательно присмотритесь к полю, где выбрали `Gradle`, то там написано compile 'com.github.imangazalievm:formvalidator:1.0.2'

Comment: Я использовал и 1.0.1 и 1.0.2, не работает. Версию 1.0.2 я загрузил сегодня, думая, что таким образом решу проблему.

Answer (score 2):

В файле **build.gradle** уровня приложения - вы точно добавили репозиторий, в котором находится ваша библиотека? Например:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'URL РЕПОЗИТОРИЯ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ'}
}
...
```

Comment: Ну, так его и не нужно добавлять, я связал библиотекус jCenter